# Transitioning Password Hashing Algorithms

Tags: javascript, php, hash

I coded up an app with a backend in PhP and got a few users. All of them have passwords, which were hashed using PhP's crypt function with the same salt every time of "PASSWORD_DEFAULT".

Now, because that code was very bad, I am transitioning to JavaScript where to hash passwords I am using the bcrypt Node Module with a randomly generated salt.

I was wondering, is there any way to save the old user's logins and make them valid even with the new hash, or are they gone forever?

EDIT FOR CODE:

Old PhP Code:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO USERS (deviceID, latitude, longitude, username, password, date_reg) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURDATE());");
        $stmt->bind_param("sddss", $deviceID, $rounded_down_lat, $rounded_down_long, $username, crypt($password, "PASSWORD_DEFAULT"));
```

New JavaScript/Node.js Code:

```
    add_user(deviceID, username, unencrypt_password, latitude, longitude, dob, gender) {
        latitude = latitude - latitude % process.env.ERR_RANGE + Number(process.env.ERR_RANGE);
        longitude = longitude - longitude % process.env.ERR_RANGE + Number(process.env.ERR_RANGE);
        var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds);
        var password = bcrypt.hashSync(unencrypt_password, salt);
        var add_user_query = mysql.format(add_user_sql, [deviceID, latitude, longitude, username, password, salt, new Date(), dob, gender]);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I don't know how the Node Module works but the hashes generated using PHP's password API includes the algorithm, cost and salt with the hash.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php "PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0)". So yes, just use bcrypt.

Comment: Do you mean Javascript or node.js? If you're hashing passwords client-side, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: So long as the JS lib you're using is `crypt()`-compatible the hashes should be interchangeable. Even if not, you should be able to implement a shim to finagle the hash storage format. Maybe post some code and example hashes and detail problems you're having.

Comment: lol also `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` isn't a salt, it's an argument to `password_hash()` specifying what hash algorithm to use. You should *definitely* post some code and example data so we can figure out what your actual question/requirements are.

Comment: bcrypt is bcrypt.. if you did it properly then they should verify in both php and the node package. When you say `crypt` you mean password_hash right?

Comment: sorry guys, I'm new to the whole password hashing stuff. I'll post the code in a new comment (also new to StackOverflow...)

Comment: @RyanBradford Please click the [edit] link under your question instead of posting the code in a comment. Code in comments is generally pretty illegible.

Comment: Just did that! Thank you :)

Comment: Sweet jesus, that's not at all how crypt() works and those hashes are worthless from a security standpoint. You *can* still use them with a crypt-compatible lib, but you *should* delete them all immediately and get your users to set new ones.

Comment: Ahhhh.... so in summary, I might be able to do it, but the best way is to really get the users to set new passwords. Just to clarify, is the Node.js way that I am currently doing things a good way?

Comment: I'm not a JS guy, but given that you're using a module named 'bcrypt' it's probably actually doing that. Just to check, you're generating these hashes *server-side*, yes?

Comment: I am yes. I store them in the database with salt and hashed-password and have the user login by passing their username and unhashed password and checking the database.